# Does init(contentsOf:encoding:) on iOS simulator works differently compared to an actual iOS device?

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to extract some files on a particular website but....
Using this function on iOS device is giving me different page source code than the one on the simulator how is that possible ? is there a workaround ?

PS: The one on the simulator is the one that should appear on both.

Comment: Is this for every page or a particular page?

Comment: It may be the case that the webpage has dynamic elements/there are different user agent strings/webpage does AB testing, etc.

Comment: @Alistra not all of them but there some... like 6 out of 10 websites.

Comment: what is the iOS simulator user agent

Comment: Unrelated, but you really should use `NSURLSession`/`URLSession` to retrieve contents of remote web service. It's asynchronous and offers richer error handling and greater control over the nature of the request being created. The `init(contentsOf:encoding:)` is synchronous (very bad), doesn't provide useful error handling for diagnostic purposes, isn't cancelable, etc.

Comment: same results using URLSession